# Synchronous fetch in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, synchronous

In Tornado's official documentation (https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html) there is an example of synchronous fetch, but when I put it in `get` method of my `IndexHandler` it returns following error:

```
  File "/home/stefan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1697, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
  File "ex1.py", line 19, in get
    client = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()
  File "/home/stefan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 107, in __init__
    self._async_client = self._io_loop.run_sync(make_client)
  File "/home/stefan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 526, in run_sync
    self.start()
  File "/home/stefan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 148, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 428, in run_forever
    'Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running')
RuntimeError: Cannot run the event loop while another loop is running
```

My code looks like:

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpclient
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        client = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()
        response = client.fetch('https://www.google.com')
        print(response.body)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app=tornado.web.Application(handlers=[(r"/", IndexHandler)],debug=True)
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I believe I should make changes in `main` in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Because as you can see in your traceback, a "synchronous" `fetch` starts it's own ioloop under the hood. The easiest to fix is to rewrite your `def get` as a coroutine (either as `async def get` or with a `@gen.coroutine` decorator) and use asynchronous fetch

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        client = tornado.httpclient.HTTPClient()
        response = await client.fetch('https://www.google.com')
        print(response.body)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I did asynchronous version similar to this one (only difference is that I used `AsyncHTTPClient` instead of yours `HTTPClient`), but I was wondering if its possible to do the same synchronously.